# How can I fix this dot product method without adjusting the number of neurons? (Java)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, neural-network, dot-product

I'm testing my neural network for XOR comparisons, and i've encountered an error i'd like to fix without altering the number of neurons in the first hidden layer. The code causing the error is:

```
public double dotProduct(int[][] a, double[][] ds) 
{
    int i;
    double sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) 
        {
            sum += a[i][j] * ds[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

is giving me a null pointer exception. The dot product calculation itself is used to generate the dot product from an inputset my neural net has been provided with.

The input set is this:

```
int inputSets[][] = 
        {
                {0, 0, 1},
                {0, 1, 1},
                {1, 0, 1},
                {0, 1, 0},
                {1, 0, 0},
                {1, 1, 1},
                {0, 0, 0}
        };
```

It's a multidimensional array containing 7 arrays. It is then used in this:

```
public double think(int[][] input) 
{
    output_from_layer1 = sigmoid(dotProd.dotProduct(input, layer1.getWeights()));

    return output_from_layer1;
}
```

The sigmoid part of the function isn't an issue, as it takes a double and 
dotProduct is supposed to output a double. The issue as far as I'm aware is that the dotProduct function is taking a larger multidimensional array, and then attempting to cross it with a smaller one (The layer1.getWeights getter that calls the weights array for that layer).

The weights of a layer are defined as such:

```
layerWeights = new double[numNeurons][inpNum];
```

and the layer that's being used in the dot product is:

```
XORlayer layer1 = new XORlayer(4, 3);
```

So 4 neurons with 3 inputs each. The issue stems from the fact that there aren't enough neurons in this layer for the amount of inputs, as far as i'm aware, which is generating the null pointer exception when there isn't anything further to multiply against the input values.

We have 12 inputs in the neurons, and 21 input values.

My main question is, is there a way to solve this issue so the dot product operation is completed successfully without simply expanding the amount of neurons the layer contains to 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291680/can-any-one-explain-why-dot-product-is-used-in-neural-network-and-what-is-the-in) might help.  As suggested there, since you're using a 2D array, matrix multiplication (instead of dot product) would likely be more appropriate.

Of course, similar to the dot product, the [dimensions must be aligned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#General_definition_of_the_matrix_product) for matrix multiplication.

`inputSets` is a 7x3 matrix and `layerWeights` is a 4x3 matrix.  The [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of `layerWeights` is a 3x4 matrix.  Now the dimensions are aligned, and the matrix multiplication results in a 7x4 matrix.

Based on the posted code, I would suggest something like this:

```
output_from_layer1 = sigmoid(matrixMult.multiply(input, transpose(layer1.getWeights())));
```